# Standalone Spark application in IntelliJ

Tags: apache-spark, intellij-idea, hadoop-yarn

I am trying to run a spark application (written in Scala) on a local server for debug. It seems that YARN is the default in the version of spark (2.2.1) that I have in the sbt build definitions, and according to an error I'm consistently getting, there is no spark/YARN server listening:

```
Client:920 - Failed to connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032: retries get failed due to exceeded maximum allowed retries number
```

According to netstat indeed there is really no port 8032 on my local server, in listening state.

How would I typically accomplish running my spark application locally, in a way bypassing this problem? I only need the application to process a small amount of data for debug, and hence would like to be able to run locally, without reliance on specific SPARK/YARN installations and setups on the local server ― that would be an ideal debug setup.

Is that possible?

My sbt definitions already bring in all the necessary spark and spark.yarn jars. The problem also reproduces when running the same project in sbt, outside of IntelliJ.

Comment: What is it that you are trying to debug exactly, is it just the spark pipeline or distributed way of application run?

Comment: Just the pipeline. Not any spark internals or any issue related to a distributed run.

Comment: [A Related Q&A helpful for debug mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57310833/lost-executor-driver-on-localhost-executor-heartbeat-timed-out)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could submit spark application in local mode with `.master("local[*]")` if you have to test pipeline with miniscule data.

Full code:

```
val spark = SparkSession
  .builder
  .appName("myapp")
  .master("local[*]")
  .getOrCreate()
```

For `spark-submit` use `--master local[*]` as one of the arguments. Refer this: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html

Note: Do not hard code master in your codebase, always try to supply these variables from commandline. This makes application reusable for local/test/mesos/kubernetes/yarn/whatever.

Comment: How are you trying to submit the application? I have added programmatic way of adding it

Comment: I'm running the application as you show in the code (just found that API the moment you posted it), rather than submitting it from the outside. It simply works. Thanks and we can probably remove our comments because the answer seems to me _as full_ without them!

Comment: A related helpful resource: https://pawanmishra.github.io/spark-stand-alone-mode/

Answer (score 2):

You can add this property to VM options in your debug configurations instead of hardcoding inside the code

```
-Dspark.master=local[2]
```