# Lost executor driver on localhost: Executor heartbeat timed out

Tags: apache-spark

I am debugging a spark application [in local mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57259426/standalone-spark-application-in-intellij/57266396#57266396). Is it feasible to disable timeouts to avoid spark crashing in the middle of a debug session, without adverse effects?

Which timeout related parameters would you suggest changing for avoiding various timeouts without crashing spark altogether?

Currently I'm encountering this one, while debugging in IntelliJ:

> Lost executor driver on localhost: Executor heartbeat timed out after
>   129006 ms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these two into the mix:

```
 val spark = SparkSession.builder()
  .config("spark.network.timeout", "10000001")
  .config("spark.executor.heartbeatInterval", "10000000")
```

Comment: Thanks. Are these specific largish values taken as infinity, or just interpreted literally?

Comment: No, they don't have any special meaning.